# How do I manage/work with cookies in a websocket based application?

Tags: http, cookies, websocket

My application uses an express server to serve a single-page-application and then the rest of the communication is handled by websockets. My issue is, how would I manage cookies if they're sent through HTTP interactions? I don't think websockets were really meant to work with cookies, but I need to use cookies for things like remembering logins. Do I need to, or is it best to, continue using HTTP for things involving cookies (and have the HTTP server run on a separate port from my websocket server)? Or is there another recommended solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets is a communication protocol, you send data back and forth just like your TCP protocol which sends HTTP application data. Browsers know how to interpret HTTP requests and responses and infere cookie data from headers. Here is the example of cookie header: `Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT;`
Now since you transfering data via Websockets all you need to do is tell browser what to do with data.

So in order to set a cookie in your browser you would use `document.cookie = "username=John Doe"` which sets a key pair cookie entry in your browser.

Please refer to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: So I should just set cookies in the browser and send them through websocket messages? And what would I do about httpOnly cookies (should I just not use them)?

Comment: @hawexp when you send your data via websocket you are free to do everything you want with data and interpret it your way. Yes you can set your cookies in browser and then send them via websockets to your server. And can do reversed as well. However concept of httpOnly and cookies in general are vanishing cause you are sending text back and forth and it is your responsibility to interpret it just like i showed you above.

Comment: Is it "standard" to send cookies through websockets? Or is it better to run a separate http server specifically for cookie handling

Comment: @hawexp there is simply no standarts in this wild environment :) What ever works best for you. But then again, ask your self a question why your web socket application needs cookies. Research what cookies are used for. and then think about your usage of them. Just keep in mind, what ever works best for you

Comment: A WebSocket connection starts its life as an HTTP request that "upgrades" the connection to WebSocket. It is during the HTTP stage that you can send/receive HTTP cookies.  Once the connection has been upgrades, HTTP cookies don't apply anymore.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that doesnt mean cockies cant be transfered via websocket lol